# Magento 2 - Checkout Issue - Invalid state change requested - Customer is charged but order not created in the admin

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3.1

We are facing an issue that is not constant, it happens very randomly and we are trying to understand. In the last 60 days, we have had 3 customers that they clicked on Place Order and the credit card was charged (authorize.net), but they never saw the success page and the order wasn't created in the backend either.
I've checked the logs and the error below appeared on the exact time of the charge in the customer's credit cart. The same error is created for all customers that had the issue:

> [2019-08-21 20:07:43] main.CRITICAL: Invalid state change requested
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException(code: 0): Invalid state
>   change requested at
>   /home/originsa/public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository/Plugin/AccessChangeQuoteControl.php:45)"} []

I have found that as per the log the error occurs when passing through here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository/Plugin/AccessChangeQuoteControl.php#L45

We are using:
Magento ver. 2.3.1

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: +1 we are having the same issue with Braintree, so I don't think this is related to the actual payment gateway used. Are you using any other plugins during checkout? We are utilizing the following: 

Module 'Wyomind_PointOfSale':
Module 'Wyomind_PickupAtStore':
Module 'Amasty_Shiprestriction':

Comment: We were able to get it fixed disabling Persistent Shopping cart. That solved the problem.

Comment: @brngyn let me try disabling Persistent Shopping Cart. Also since your last post have you encountered this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This has been a huge pain to track this down due to the inconsistent/random nature of the issue. We are also using Wyomind_PointOfSale so if it is related to a 3rd party extension, that might be the problem extension. Thank you for advise on disabling the persistent cart, we will try that.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue with Purchase Order method:(

Comment: Any solution you got?